# Graph Theory Cycles in Nonseparable graphs

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $k$ be the maximum length of a cycle in a nonseparable graph $G$. Prove that if $C$ and $C'$ are any two $k$-cycles in $G$, then $C$ and $C'$ have at least two vertices in common.

Nonseparable meaning biconnected. Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score -1):

> Theorem. If the graph G has a vertex v that is connected to a vertex of the component G1 of G, then v is also a vertex of G1.

Suppose there exists one and only edge connecting C to C'. Removing this edge would yield two connected components.

Suppose there exists two edges connecting C to C'. Removing one edge would yield one connected component. C and C' have at least two vertices in common.

Comment: If C and C' were connected with two edges, wouldn't C and C' no longer be a k-cycle (maximum length cycle)?

Comment: Why not? @Alex.

Comment: Despite the acceptance, this does not answer the question. A non-separable graph is a connected graph which is not disconnected by removing a **vertex**.

Comment: "If the graph G has a vertex v that is connected to a vertex of the component G1 of G, then v is also a vertex of G1." @Brian M. Scott

Comment: So? That doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: It's a Lemma that helps me answer. Basically if there exists an edge connecting C to C', that implies 1 common vertex (each C and C') share a vertex with the other graph. 2 edges implies 2 common vertices, etc..

Comment: It’s a lemma that requires proof, and what you’ve written in the answer does not prove it. For example, you have not ruled out the possibility that there is no edge connecting $C$ to $C'$; this is entirely possible even if $G$ is connected.

Comment: How so @BrianM.Scott? Please draw an example.

Comment: @Don: The theorem in the original question is true, so there is no example, but you have not given any argument that proves this.

Comment: "For example, you have not ruled out the possibility that there is no edge connecting C to C′; this is entirely possible even if G is connected." I can't visualize such a graph; if C and C' weren't connected by an edge, then they would be separate k-cycles.